# Compilation Shell Script Invocation Error SQL Cipher Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, sqlcipher

Building with xcode 5 and ios sdk 6.1

Subprojects - SQL Cipher , SSL Crypto

Compiling Succeeds BUT with 2 errors :

- i386/_types.h - not found
- libsqlcipher.a - not found and in products(under its project its in red - missing)

Tried everything to resolve two errors - no success..

Error i get : 
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.1.sdk/usr/include/machine/_types.h:32:10: fatal error: 'i386/_types.h' file not found

## include "i386/_types.h"

```
     ^
```

1 error generated.
make: *** [keywordhash.h] Error 1
Command /bin/sh emitted errors but did not return a nonzero exit code to indicate failure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have finally succeeded to resolve this..

1. Open SQL Cipher subproject separately and build it.
2. Close subproject
3. Open main project, clean and build it

That was the solution for me..